# Mongoose: accessing the doc returned by Model.find() query before getting to chained populate()

Tags: mongoose

I have this query:

```
Book.findById(someId).populate({
 path: 'pages'
}).exec(function(err) {});
```

Mongoose documentation states that first, the query to find a document in `Books` collection is fulfilled, and then it proceeds to query for the children documents in `Pages` collection.

I would like to access the document returned by the `Book.findById()` query before getting to the chained `populate()` method. How can I do this?

I need this to set a value in `options` object for `populate()` like this:

```
Book.findById(someId).populate({
  path: 'pages',
  options: {
    skip: book.pages.indexOf(someElementInPagesArray) // Need to access doc
  }
}).exec(function(err) {});
```

Hope you guys can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call populate separately like this:

```
Book.findById(someId).exec(function(err, book) {
  book.populate({
    path: 'pages',
    options: {
      skip: book.pages.indexOf(someElementInPagesArray)
    }
  }, function(err, book) {
    // Populate done
  })
});
```

Comment: Really? I thought about this, but I assumed it was not an option as I could not find a Model#populate method in the Mongoose API. I figured populate() would only be available for queries and not for documents. I'll wive it a try.

Comment: Yeah, it is listed as [Model.populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate) and not Model#populate in the docs.
The one I used is [Document#populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate)